# read xml content from http endpoint like a map in Java

Tags: java, xml, http, parsing

How could I get value based on a key from an XML content http enpoint, so it is something like

```
<authority.result result="found 7 matches" startToken="xxxxxxx">
<TestEntry keyId="0right0" test="test" valueId="rightValue123" version="1"/>
<TestEntry keyId="0wrong" test="test" valueId="0wrongValue" version="1"/>
<TestEntry keyId="0wrong0" test="test" valueId="wrong" version="1"/>
</authority.result>
```

I would like to get the `valueId` when `keyId=="0right0"` only, I previously wrote following but could not get value for a specific key.

```
            URL url = new URL(endpoint);
            XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(url.openStream());
            String latest;
            while (reader.hasNext()) {
                if (reader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                    if (reader.getLocalName().equals("valueId")) {
                        latest = reader.getElementText();
                        return latest;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish `XML` element from an attribute. To read attribute name and value you have to use `getAttributeName` and `getAttributeValue` methods respectively.

Below you find example code how to read attributes:

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamConstants;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Optional;

public class XmlStreamApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XMLStreamException {
        ...
        XMLStreamReader reader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(stream);
        Optional<String> value = findValueForTestEntry(reader, "0right0");
        System.out.println(value);
    }

    private static Optional<String> findValueForTestEntry(XMLStreamReader reader, String keyValue) throws XMLStreamException {
        while (reader.hasNext()) {
            if (reader.next() == XMLStreamConstants.START_ELEMENT) {
                String localName = reader.getLocalName();
                if ("TestEntry".equals(localName)) {
                    Optional<String> optionalValue = getValueForKey(reader, keyValue);
                    if (optionalValue.isPresent()) {
                        return optionalValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    private static Optional<String> getValueForKey(XMLStreamReader reader, String keyValue) {
        String value = "";
        boolean found = false;
        for (int attr = reader.getAttributeCount() - 1; attr >= 0; attr--) {
            QName attributeName = reader.getAttributeName(attr);
            if (attributeName.getLocalPart().equals("keyId")) {
                found = keyValue.equals(reader.getAttributeValue(attr));
            }
            if (attributeName.getLocalPart().equals("valueId")) {
                value = reader.getAttributeValue(attr);
            }
        }
        return found ? Optional.of(value) : Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

Above code prints:

```
Optional[rightValue123]
```

Comment: nitpick: `if (attributeName.getLocalPart().equals("sku")) {
                value = reader.getAttributeValue(attr);
            }` could have a `break` in it right? Especially when we only need one value of it

Comment: @user8142520, it is not always true. Assume we find `value` but `key` was not found yet. If we break from a loop, method will return empty `Optional` object. You would have to check whether `value` and `key` attributes were already checked. If yes, we can safely break from a loop. In other case we need to check other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an xpath to get to the desired value :

`string(//TestEntry[@keyId="0right0"]/@valueId)`